# how to fix yum errors on my RHEL 5.3 box

Tags: linux, installation, yum, rhel-5

I am getting errors when I try to install any package on my RHEL 5.3 linux box. I've previously installed mc(midnight commander) using yum but recently it started failing.

How can I fix it ?

thank you,

I've inserted a log of a session below.

```
[root@anjanb ~]# yum install multitail
Repository engineering-update is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository engineering-install is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository emergency-update is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository emergency-install is listed more than once in the configuration
emergency-install                                        |  951 B     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           |  215 B     00:00
emergency-desktop-update                                 |  951 B     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           |  222 B     00:00
emergency-desktop-install                                |  951 B     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           |  223 B     00:00
emergency-engineering-update                             |  951 B     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           |  226 B     00:00
emergency-engineering-install                            |  951 B     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           |  227 B     00:00
engineering-install                                      |  951 B     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           |  157 B     00:00
engineering-update                                       | 1.1 kB     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           | 6.3 kB     00:00
engineering-update                                             41/41
desktop-install                                          |  951 B     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           |  157 B     00:00
workstation                                              | 1.3 kB     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           | 265 kB     00:00
workstation                                                    1205/1205
base                                                     | 1.3 kB     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           | 614 kB     00:00
base                                                           1953/1953
desktop-update                                           | 1.1 kB     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           |  36 kB     00:00
desktop-update                                                 142/142
cisco-linux-common                                       | 1.1 kB     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           | 5.3 kB     00:00
cisco-linux-common                                             18/18
vt                                                       | 1.3 kB     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           | 8.8 kB     00:00
vt                                                             40/40
emergency-update                                         | 1.1 kB     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           |  82 kB     00:00
emergency-update                                               190/190
cisco-linux-desktop                                      | 1.1 kB     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           |  18 kB     00:00
cisco-linux-desktop                                            62/62
adobe-linux-i386                                         |  951 B     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           |  12 kB     00:00
http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/i386/repodata/primary.xml.gz: [Errno -1] Me                                           tadata file does not match checksum
Trying other mirror.
primary.xml.gz                                           |  12 kB     00:00
http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/i386/repodata/primary.xml.gz: [Errno -1] Me                                           tadata file does not match checksum
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/primary.xml.gz from adobe-linux-i386: [Errno 256] No mo                                           re mirrors to try.
[root@anjanb ~]#
[root@anjanb ~]#
[root@anjanb ~]# yum install multitail
Repository engineering-update is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository engineering-install is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository emergency-update is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository emergency-install is listed more than once in the configuration
primary.xml.gz                                                                                      |  12 kB     00:00
http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/i386/repodata/primary.xml.gz: [Errno -1] Metadata file does not match checksum
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/primary.xml.gz from adobe-linux-i386: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
[root@anjanb ~]#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can't really be fixed, unless it's a network issue (try opening the URL in a browser). Pass `--disablerepo=adobe-linux-i386` to yum to disable the repo temporarily.

Comment: thank you. can't I point my yum at different repositories ?

Comment: Adobe only has one location for their repository.

Comment: but why do I need to go to adobe for my packages ?

Comment: Because presumably at some point someone wanted Flash on the system.

Answer (score 0):

The below command line might help:

```
yum clean all && yum makecache && yum update
```

Comment: true, but the error doesn't look like a non-reachable repo server.

refer:
http://plone.lucidsolutions.co.nz/linux/rpm/yum-metadata-file-does-not-match-checksum

Answer (score 0):

Go to /eyc/yum.repos.d, and chek you don't have duplicates in there (the output shows complaints in that direction).
Look at the different repositories, and make sure you really need them ("yum list installed" tells you where each package comes from).